# Boostrap datepicker, picker appears way up

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Found out that for a particular page the `bootstrap-datepicker` popup appears way at the top.

Here's the html of these elements

```
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 font-normal">When does this job start?</label>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
    <input class="form-control" id="start-date" placeholder="Select a date">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 input-padding"></div>

<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">Job post will expire on</label>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
    <input class="form-control" id="end-date" placeholder="Select a date">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 input-padding"></div>
```

and a recording of this https://youtu.be/ZB1AxU-pzyM

Comment: Make sure the datepicker is wrapped in a container that has a position: relative; on it.

Comment: tried that; `<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6" style="position: relative;">
   <input class="form-control" id="start-date" placeholder="Select a date">
  </div>` and still got the same error

Comment: I would need to see a demo to have access to the element inspector. Without it, I can't help you unfortunately.

Comment: http://kazilynk.com/accounts/login/ username: test@testing.com pass: test when you login it should take you to the application details. There's "When does this job start?" field which has start date if you click it and can view the top of the site you should see the datepicker at the top.